# Следующая ячейка в объединённых зонах

Tags: excel, vba

Мне нужно заполнить определённые ячейки в моём формате. Хочу чтоб автоматом переходил между этими ячейками. Для этого я пометил эти ячейки как зона заполнения Union areas так как они не по порядку. Код проверяет находится ли изменяемая ячейка в union а потом выделяет следующую ячейку. К сожалению не смог решить проблему без each cell и двух if. Обычный index cell на union не работает.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
Set op = Union(Range("A1", "A2"), Range("A4", "A5"), Range("A9", "A10")) 
 If Not Intersect(Target, op) Is Nothing Then
   For Each cell In op 
     If te = 1 Then
       cell.Select
       Exit Sub
      End If 
    If cell.Address = Target.Address Then
         te = 1
    End If 
  Next cell 
  End If 
 End Sub
```

Общая идея чтоб переходить между заранее известными ячейками, на подобии того как выбераешь разные ячейки зажимая контрл, а потом переходишь между выделенными энтером

Comment: 1. Я, например, ничего не понял - что вам надо, что вы хотите, в чём заключается ваша проблема. 2. Советую привести свой код. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Denis добавил код, надеюсь что сейчас понятней.

Answer (score 0):

Нормальное решение. Другое проще - не придумалось.

Можно чуточку оптимизировать код автора:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim op As Range, c As Range
Dim te As Boolean
    Set op = Union(Range("A1:A2"), Range("A4:A5"), Range("A9:A10"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, op) Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In op
            If c.Address = Target.Address Then
                te = True
            Else
                If te = True Then c.Select: Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
' -----------------------------------
```

То, что ниже, сложнее. Только как вариант, некоторые мысли могут быть полезны.

Если в сформированном диапазоне много значений или работа с ним частая, заполнение можно вынести в отдельную процедуру и заполнять диапазон один раз. Код разместить в общем модуле:

```
' публичные переменные, могут использоваться в модуле листа
Public ArrR(), op As Range

' заполнение массива
Sub FillingOfArrays()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        ' создание диапазона из отдельных диапазонов листа
        Set op = Union(.Range("A1:A2"), .Range("A4:A5"), .Range("A9:A10"))
    End With

    ReDim ArrR(1 To 2, 1 To 1) ' определение начальной размерности массива
    ' первая "строка" - для записи номеров строк, вторая - для номеров столбцов
    ' если количество ячеек диапазона op заранее известно,
    ' в цикле переопределение размерности (ReDim Preserve) можно исключить

    For Each c In op
        j = j + 1 ' счетчик элементов массива
        ReDim Preserve ArrR(1 To 2, 1 To j) ' добавляем элемент массива
        ArrR(1, j) = c.Row ' запись строки адреса ячейки
        ArrR(2, j) = c.Column ' запись столбца адреса ячейки
    Next c
End Sub
```

В модуль листа:

```
' перед работой с диапазоном нужно заполнить массив ArrR и диапазон op
' пример: при активации листа
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call FillingOfArrays ' к заполнению массива
End Sub

' при изменении значения переход между ячейками диапазона
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim j As Long
    If Not Intersect(Target, op) Is Nothing Then ' только при изменениях в op
        With Target ' родитель
            For j = 1 To UBound(ArrR, 2) ' цикл по массиву строка/столбец
                If .Row = ArrR(1, j) And .Column = ArrR(2, j) Then
                    ' строка/столбец изменяемой ячейки найдены в массиве
                    If j = UBound(ArrR, 2) Then ' если последняя ячейка диапазона
                        ' переход к первой ячейке диапазона
                        Cells(ArrR(1, 1), ArrR(2, 1)).Select
                    Else
                        ' переход к следующей ячейке диапазона
                        Cells(ArrR(1, j + 1), ArrR(2, j + 1)).Select
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Плюс такого решения: код заполнения массива может быть использован для работы не только на одном листе. Запуск можно организовать при активации любого листа.

Еще одно - возможность возврата из последней ячейки в начало диапазона.

Не лишней будет очистка памяти (например, при закрытии книги):

```
Set op = Nothing
```

Comment: спс за ответ.
1) Сложный ответ не понял, там функция FillingOfArrays вообще не вызывается. В любом случае он мне меньше подходит
2) Спасибо за оптимизацию! Воспользуюсь. Кста, у меня Range "op" определён через Name Manager в Exel
3) Разочарован что нету нумерации ячеек в Union по типу Range.Cell(1) ,  Range.Cell(2) и так далее :(

Comment: Это лишь пример организации расчетов - чтобы не формировать диапазон каждый раз при любом изменении на листе. FillingOfArrays можно вызвать при активации листа (в ответе об этом написано). После завершения работы с диапазоном принудительно очищайте созданный объект (*Set op = Nothing*)

Comment: Добавил в ответ комментарии к коду